# Necesito cambiar el contenido de un richTextBox de manera aleatoria cada vez que se oprima un botón y cuando abre la página al principio

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer un juego en el que un richTextBox va a tener un texto bíblico y los botones tendrán el nombre de la cita mostrandose de manera aleatoria a traves de un List. No tengo problemas al generar el texto de los botones, pero cómo tengo que mostrar un texto en el richTextBox cuando abre la página al final no tengo más texto que asignarle al richTextBox.

```
  public void EscogerCita()
    {
        while (citas.Count != 0)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            index = random.Next(citas.Count);
            citaTxt.Add(citas[index]);
            citas.RemoveAt(index); 

        }
    }

    private void AsignarCitaBtn()
    {
        while (botones.Count != 0)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int index = rnd.Next(botones.Count);
            txtBtns.Add(botones[index]);
            botones.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        Btn.Text = txtBtns[0];
        Btn2.Text = txtBtns[1];
        Btn3.Text = txtBtns[2];
        Btn4.Text = txtBtns[3];
        Btn5.Text = txtBtns[4];
        Btn6.Text = txtBtns[5];

        txtBtn = Btn.Text;
        txtBtn2 = Btn2.Text;
        txtBtn3 = Btn3.Text;
        txtBtn4 = Btn4.Text;
        txtBtn5 = Btn5.Text;
        txtBtn6 = Btn6.Text;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBtn == "Filipenses 4:13" && "Todo lo puedo en Cristo." == richTextBox1.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");
            label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[1];
            Btn.Visible = false;


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
            Btn.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[1];
        }


    }
    private void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtBtn2 == "Juan 3:16" && "Porque de tal manera amó Dios al mundo, que ha dado a su Hijo unigénito para que todo el que cree en El, no se pierda, mas tenga vida eterna." == richTextBox1.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");
            puntos += 5;
            label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[2];
            Btn2.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
            Btn2.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[2];
        }


    }

    private void Btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtBtn3 == "2da Timoteo 3:16-17"  && "Toda la Escritura es inspirada por Dios, y útil para enseñar, para redarguir, para corregir, para instruir en justicia a fin de quel el hombre de Dios sea perfecto, eternamente preparado para toda buena obra." == richTextBox1.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");
            puntos += 5;
            label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[3];
            Btn3.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
            Btn3.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[3];
        }

    }

    private void Btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtBtn4 == "Salmos 23:6" && richTextBox1.Text == "Ciertamente el bien y la misericordia me seguirán todos los días de mi vida y en la casa de Jehová moraré por largos días.")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");
            puntos = +5;
            label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
            Btn4.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[4];

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
            Btn4.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[4];
        }

    }

    private void Btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtBtn5 == "Salmos 91:1" && richTextBox1.Text == "El que habita al abrigo del Altísimo morará bajo la sombra del omnipotente.")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");
            puntos += 5;
            label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
            Btn5.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[5];

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
            Btn5.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[5];
        }

    }

    private void Btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBtn6 == "Romanos 5:1" && richTextBox1.Text == "Justificados, pues, por la fe, tenemos paz para con Dios por medio de nuestro Señor Jesucristo.")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");

            Btn6.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
            Btn6.Visible = false;
        }

    }

}
```

Si pueden observar el botón Btn6 no tiene para generar un texto nuevo, es decir que si se oprime ese botón al comienzo ya no se generará un nuevo texto y el juego se dañaría.

Qué solución me recomiendan?

Por aquí están las listas y su contenido

```
    List<string> citas = new List<string>();
    List<string> citaTxt = new List<string>();
    List<string> botones = new List<string>();
    List<string> txtBtns = new List<string>();

       citas.Add("Todo lo puedo en Cristo.");
        citas.Add("Porque de tal manera amó Dios al mundo, que ha dado a su Hijo unigénito para que todo el que cree en El, no se pierda, mas tenga vida eterna.");
        citas.Add("Toda la Escritura es inspirada por Dios, y útil para enseñar, para redarguir, para corregir, para instruir en justicia a fin de quel el hombre de Dios sea perfecto, eternamente preparado para toda buena obra.");
        citas.Add("Ciertamente el bien y la misericordia me seguirán todos los días de mi vida y en la casa de Jehová moraré por largos días.");
        citas.Add("El que habita al abrigo del Altísimo morará bajo la sombra del omnipotente.");
        citas.Add("Justificados, pues, por la fe, tenemos paz para con Dios por medio de nuestro Señor Jesucristo.");

        botones.Add("Filipenses 4:13");
        botones.Add("Juan 3:16");
        botones.Add("2da Timoteo 3:16-17");
        botones.Add("Salmos 23:6");
        botones.Add("Salmos 91:1");
        botones.Add("Romanos 5:1");
```

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta se agradecería que marcaras tu pregunta como respondida para que otro también pueda aprovecharla.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que empiezas asignando en el método:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

la segunda posición de tu array cuando haces:

```
richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[1];
```

Cambia todas las asignaciones de los diferentes `richTextBox` por el índice actual -1. Esto es porque los arrays tienen los índices en base 0 y el primer índice no es el 1 sino el 0.

Comment: No he entendido tu comentario. Si preguntas dónde hay que cambiarlo es en los diferentes métodos que dicen qué hace cada click de los botones.

Comment: Mis disculpas fue que se cargó el comentario sin haberlo terminado. A lo que me refiero es que en Initialize Component(); tiene que cargarse un texto en el richTextBox por eso en el botón Btn se muestra así `richTextBox1.Text = citaTxt[1];` ya que en `InitializeComponent();` tengo esto `richTextBox.Text = citaTxt[0];` Lo que necesito hacer es que no importa cual botón sea si se presionó al final pues ya no aparece otro texto, porque el juego se acaba.

Comment: Si se ha acabado el juego entiendo que en el `richTextBox` pondrás otro mensaje tipo "Game Over" o algo así. Si no es que no he entendido bien tu juego.

Answer (score 0):

Para que sea más genérico crea un número aleatorio que no exceda el tamaño de tu lista y luego con una sintaxis similar puedes mostrarlos:

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
int randonNum = rnd.Next(list.Count);    
Btn.Text = txtBtns[randonNum];
```

Answer (score 0):

a lo que he entendido podrías validar que no hayas usado alguno de los valores en citaTxt.